# Is it possible to convert dates when reindexing data in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I used to have a property like this in mapping:

```
  "dueDate": {
    "type": "text"
  }
```

Now I have changed it to this:

```
  "dueDate": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "dd.MM.yyyy.",
    "copy_to": "_content"
  }
```

When trying to reindex the old data, an error is returned:

```
{\"type\":\"mapper_parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"failed to parse [dueDate]\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Invalid format: \\\"15.09.2021. 06:49:18\\\" is malformed at \\\" 06:49:18\\\"\"}},\"status\":400}
```

Most `dueDates` have data with format "15.09.2021."/"dd.MM.yyyy." as required, but there are a few exceptions of different formats like in the error message, synchronized by mistake.

Is it possible to automatically keep only dates from such data? Or just ignore them as the last recourse?

Online I have found an example like this for converting data:

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": "A"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "B"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "long milliSinceEpoch = ctx._source.remove(\"dt_1\"); Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliSinceEpoch); ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of('Z')); ctx._source.dt_1 = zdt;"
  }
}
```

but it's not clear how to take account of all the possible date formats that could exist in the index, to convert them.

Comment: From what I understand you may have different date formats that can cause exceptions during re-indexing. In this case I think you have to map all the possibilities and create the correct script to avoid errors.
Another option is to set the parameter [conflicts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-api-request-body) to processed so that errors are ignored and the re-indexing is finished. After that you can search separately in the new index the fields that do not have the converted date and evaluate the reason separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ignore_malformed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html) option. But it seems your dates also sometimes have a time. So I suggest that you also tweak the date format to allow for an optional time. You can specify multiple formats with a pipe, e.g. `"format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||strict_date_optional_time ||epoch_millis"`.